# FlatList use numColumns shows Elements type is invalid

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I use FlatList to show image like this:
[image]

But when i add `numColumns={2}` in `FlatList` it will show the error:

```
Element type is invalid
```

[image]

The strange thing is there is no error if i use `numColumns={1}`

I can't figure it out. Any one can give me some suggestion ? Thanks in advance.

Here is i use my FlatList code

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
const equalWidth = width / 2;

class MainActivity extends Component {
  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return item.map(value => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Image
            style={{ height: 150, width: equalWidth }}
            source={{ uri: value.photoHref }}
            resizeMode="cover"
          />
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={movieData}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        horizontal={false}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        numColumns={2}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the json for the `movieData` ?

Comment: Yes , the data is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add explicit `width` to the `Flatlist` image, it can be simply done by providing flex to the parent wrapper.

Since the [renderItem](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#renderitem) expects a `React.Element` in *return*, therefore you can do

```
renderItem = ({item}) => (
       <View style={{flex: 1, height: 150, margin: 5}}> <== Adding margin(Optional), width will be automatically scaled
           item.map(value => (
             <Image
                style={{flex: 1}}
                source={{ uri: value.photoHref }}
                resizeMode="cover"
             />
           ))
       </View>
   )
```

[Here's](https://snack.expo.io/SJai8Wq2G) a sample snack wrt to your code

Comment: Thanks you. I try your code still no working :( . It just changes the image size but when i set numColumns={2} still shows the same error.

Comment: I've added a snack link, try checking that for any inconsistencies

Comment: Thank  you very much. The link app shows Expo has stopped. I will try it on pure project.

Comment: You can try it on your `app.js` file directly.

Comment: Yes, your code is fine in pure project. I will try compare with yours. Still i fix the issue. Thanks for your help truly, @Priitish.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @riwu answer, please add prop `columnWrapperStyle={{width:"50%}}`to the FlatList. i.e. how much columns you give add the respective width to the prop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Adding to @riwu answer  i try to add `columnWrapperStyle={{width:"50%}}` to the `FlatList`  set numColumns={2} the screen just shows one column.

Comment: Try adding flex to view and one more thing is, why have you put item.map inside renderItem? Usually renderItem returns only one element.

Comment: Try `<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>` and set `numColumns={2}` still one columns.  Because i fetch an API data that my item is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap your array of components with a `View`:

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <View>
    {item.map((value) => (
      <View>
        <Image
          style={{ height: 150, width: equalWidth }}
          source={{ uri: value.photoHref }}
          resizeMode="cover"
        />
      </View>
    ))}
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i try your code , there is no error any more, but the `numColumns` is still show one column on device.

Comment: Try reducing `equalWidth`, there might be padding/margin/rounding issues. Inspect the element to make sure it's not occupying more than half the available space.

Comment: I set width like 50 or 30 , its still show one column :( .I take a reference from `https://github.com/moorthysubu/react-native-flatList-grid/blob/master/FlatListGridView/src/App.js`  Still try to find the issue.

Comment: Might be the 2 outer `View` rather than the `Image` taking up the space. Try swap the component with something simple to see if it works. Also, if you just want 2 `Image` per row, your `renderItem` should return only 1 `Image`, with `numColumns={2}`.